# fishshell aliases using &&

Tags: git, alias, fish

When making aliases using fishshell I am running into issues when trying to execute commands with &&.

eg. `alias gac 'git add . && git commit -m'`

`&&` is not apparently allowed in fishshell and you are supposed to use `&` or `and`.

other things that don't work:
`alias gac 'git add . & git commit -m'`
`alias gac 'git add . and git commit -m'`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Glenn provided the correct answer but I wanted to point out that `&` in fish means the same thing it does in POSIX shells like bash. It puts the job in the background. It has nothing to do with `&&` or the fish `and` special command. Also, a fish `alias` is just shorthand for defining a `function`. It's not the same thing as a bash alias.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`and` is a **command**](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#and), so it needs to be separated from the command that came before

```
alias gac 'git add .; and git commit -m'
```

or

```
function gac -a commit_msg
    git add .
    and git commit -m $commit_msg
end
```